# How to prevent non-blocking in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is part of my code.

```
var project_url;
project_url = getProjectUrl(req,name);

var collection = db.get('project');     
collection.insert({
     "id" : projectId,
     "name" : name,
     "url" : project_url
}, function(err,doc){
     if(err){
         res.send("There was a problem");
     }
});

var collection2 = db.get('project_details');
collection2.insert({
    "id" : projectId,
    "media" : media
}, function(err,doc){
     if(err){
        res.send("There was a problem");
     }
});
```

Using Node.js with MongoDB, I want to insert data to database AFTER function getProjectUrl, which returns a string value, has finished. However, it run asynchronously so that collection.insert and collection2.insert executed before getProjectUrl returns a value. Therefore, when I checked the database, the project_url is null. How to make the inserts executed after getProjectUrl returns a value?

Comment: You should create a callback function that uses the values after the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your function `getProjectUrl` with callback, for example

```
function getProjectUrl(req, name, callback) {
    var result = 'foo'; // I'm not sure how you get it

    callback(result);
}
```

and then

```
getProjectUrl(req, name, function(project_url) {
    var collection = db.get('project');     
    collection.insert({
         "id" : projectId,
         "name" : name,
         "url" : project_url
    }, function(err,doc){
         if(err){
             res.send("There was a problem");
         }
    });

    var collection2 = db.get('project_details');
    collection2.insert({
        "id" : projectId,
        "media" : media
    }, function(err,doc){
         if(err){
            res.send("There was a problem");
         }
    });
});
```